# Android ListView item click doesn't go to the right screen

Tags: android, jsoup

I have made an App that lists some links that I parse from a Html page using `jsoup`.

The list shows the title of the link and an arrow that should have the link. But when I select any item of them I only get the last link.

Here's my `Controller`:

```
public class Controller extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_view);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("");
        linkList = new ArrayList<>();
        http = this.getString(R.string.http);
        url = this.getString(R.string.path1);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        new GetLinks().execute();
    }

    private class GetLinks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Document doc;
            Elements links;

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                links = doc.getElementsByClass("processlink");
                linkList = ParseHTML(links);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Controller.this, linkList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TITLE, LINK},
                    new int[]{R.id.title});
            //Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute: "+ getString(R.id.link));
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ParseHTML(Elements links) throws IOException {

        if (links != null) {

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> linkList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Element link : links) {
                final String linkhref = http + link.select("a").attr("href");
                String linktext = link.text();

                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                            View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse(linkhref));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                    }
                });

                HashMap<String, String> student = new HashMap<>();
                student.put(TITLE, linktext);
                student.put(LINK, linkhref);

                linkList.add(student);
            }

            return linkList;
        }
        else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get html from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get html from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's the `main_view.xml`

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

And last but not least, `list_item.xml`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Title"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/link"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/link" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/link"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/title" />
```

If I log the title and the link, I get all the links and the title but, not in the app.

So my question is how I get the links to work as a list and not just the last link?

Comment: your code needs lots of fixing , follow the best practice , use POJO classes or maintain a string list of strings , my advice would be follow some tutorial first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `linkList` is already declared in global I guess. So you're fine to go with this.

I would love to suggest you some edits in your code anyway. You might initialize your `ListView` fully in your `onCreate` function. Declare your `Adapter` as a global variable.

You might also consider setting the `onClickListener` of your `ListView` items here inside `onCreate` function too.

```
// Declare the adapter globally.
private ListAdapter adapter;

// Declare the linkList as an ArrayList of Student object
private ArrayList<Student> linkList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_view);
    // ... Setup toolbar
    // ... Setup http and url string

    // Setup ListView
    linkList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Initialize the adapter
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Controller.this, linkList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TITLE, LINK},
                new int[]{R.id.title});        

    // Set the adapter here
    lv.setAdapter(adapter); 

    // Setup the ListView item click
    setupListViewItemClick();

    // Now execute the AsyncTask
    new GetLinks().execute();
}
```

Here's the `setupListViewItemClick` function which might look like this.

```
private void setupListViewItemClick() {
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int position, long id) {

            // Get the student by the position of the adapter.
            Student student = linkList.get(position);
            String linkhref = student.getLink();

            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(linkhref));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Hence, you need to modify your `ParseHTML` function.

```
private ArrayList<Student> ParseHTML(Elements links) throws IOException {

    if (links != null) {
    // Removed the initialization of HashMap

        for (Element link : links) {
            String linktext = link.text();

            // ** Removed the onClickListener **

            Student student = new Student();
            student.setTitle(linktext);
            student.setLink(link);

            // Just add the items here
            linkList.add(student);
        }

        return linkList;

    } else {
        // The else part goes here
    }

    return null;
}
```

Finally, in your `AsyncTask` you need to modify your `onPostExecute` a bit like this to notify your `linkList` has been populated with data so the adapter refreshes it.

```
private class GetLinks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        Document doc;
        Elements links;

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            links = doc.getElementsByClass("processlink");
            linkList = ParseHTML(links);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // Just call the notifyDatasetChanged to notify the adapter 
        // to reload the data from the linkList
        adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
    }
}
```

**Update**

@PanveetSingh stated, `student` is not an object but a `HashMap`. Sorry I missed that part earlier. You might consider creating a class called `Student` like this.

```
public class Student {
    public String title;
    public String linkhref;

    public Student() {}

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setLink(Element link) {
        this.linkhref = "http://" + link.select("a").attr("href");
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return this.linkhref;
    }
}
```

Your `ParseHTML` function and the other functions are modified accordingly.

Comment: `student` is a hashmap , `student.getLink()` won't work , you need to iterate twice in hashmap to get link string , code needs lot of fixing

Comment: Sorry didn't see that earlier. Thanks for the catch. Hope this is good to go now. You can have a look now and tell me if anything is wrong here again. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy :)

Comment: nice, but the adapter does not work after the ArrayList is changed I just get an error saying it wants java...java.util.Map<java.Lang.String.?>> and changing the linkList to (List<? extends Map<String, ?>>) linkList in the adapter does not help and there is no notifyDatasetChanged() and in Student class getTitle() and getLink() should be string not void. but I am not sure how to fix the adabter

Comment: You might have to write your custom adapter. There are a plenty of resources in the internet regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ParseHTML(Elements links)` method

```
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                    View view, int position, long id) {
                String theRealLink = linkList.get(position);
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse(theRealLink));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });
```

The linkList also needs to be `final`.

(Also remember that in Java, `methodNamesShouldBeInThisFormat()`)